# TortoiseSVN marks files as conflicted, but no conflict can be seen in TortoiseMerge

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

Good morning

In windows explorer I can see that some files of my SVN versioned project have the Tortoise conflict icon with the corresponding .mine, .oldrevision, .newrevision files.

When I open the files with TortoiseMerge (using the Edit conflicts context menu option), I see no red-marked code lines at all. I can just mark the conflict as resolved and close the TortoiseMerge editor. Then the corresponding file icon is the normal, no-clinflict one and the .mine, .oldrevision, .newrevision files are gone.

Would you know why this happen, and how could I resolve this problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

most likely, the file is encoded in utf-16. SVN can only merge utf-8 or ANSI/ASCII encoded files properly. Since it can not merge utf-16 encoded files, it marks those as conflicted.

TortoiseMerge however can handle utf-16 encoded files just fine, that's why it doesn't show a conflict but just a successful merge result.